# How create App/Utility/WebApp from the AzureRm Terraform Provider?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I don't know "GO", but I have been a developer/engineer for over 30 years, so I shouldn't have any trouble figuring it out... What I am looking for is a start/example/tutorial, etc. of how I might use the source code from the terraform azurerm provider repo (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm), build a standalone app/utility and then run it.

What I want to know, exactly, is why their code returns a specific error message during a "terraform plan" while reading the remote state. My thought is, why not just "strip" their code down to that particular function (and any "required" functions) and just run it.

(I want to run the resourceStorageAccountRead function, located in "internal\services\storage\storage_account_resource.go".)

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the golang code, Download Golang for your OS from [**here**](https://go.dev/doc/install). ***Create one Folder in your VS Code and create a file called main.go, Right click on that file> Open with integrated terminal and and run the command*** below:-

```golang
go mod init github.com/sid24desai/hello
OR
go mod init hello
```

go.mod file will be created like below:-

```golang
module hello

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v68.0.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest v14.2.0+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest v0.11.29 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/adal v0.9.23 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/date v0.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/validation v0.3.1 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/logger v0.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/Azure/go-autorest/tracing v0.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/agext/levenshtein v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/apparentlymart/go-textseg/v13 v13.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/fatih/color v1.13.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4 v4.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/errwrap v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-azure-helpers v0.57.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-azure-sdk v0.20230626.1153114 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-cty v1.4.1-0.20200414143053-d3edf31b6320 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-hclog v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-uuid v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/go-version v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2 v2.16.2 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/logutils v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go v0.14.3 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-log v0.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2 v2.26.1 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.12 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.14 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/copystructure v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/go-testing-interface v1.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/go-wordwrap v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/reflectwalk v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/tombuildsstuff/giovanni v0.20.0 // indirect
    github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack v4.0.4+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v4 v4.3.12 // indirect
    github.com/vmihailenco/tagparser v0.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/zclconf/go-cty v1.13.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.10.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.8.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.9.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.7 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.1 // indirect
)
```

Now, Copy your storage_account_resource.go code in the main.go file and import all the github modules by running the command go get module, Refer below:-

If you have a Go extension installed in your VS Code you can hover over the github module with red swiggly lines and use Quick Fix feature like below:-

[image]

Or run the code below for the installation of individual packages

```golang
go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/storage/mgmt/2021-09-01/storage
```

after installing all the packages, you can change the required variables with your storage account and then run the below command to run the golang file:-

```golang
go run main.go
```

This will run your Go file.

You can refer the code to deploy Storage account via Terraform from [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account), Refer the steps below:-

My main.tf:-

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.10.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "xxxxe97cb2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxed-af9038592395"
client_id = "xxxx38-6d26a31435cb"
client_secret = "xxxxx-CS0ifbLE"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "siliconrg65"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "versiliconstrg54"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Run the commands below in your VS code terminal to apply the terraform code:-

```
terraform init, 
terraform plan -out main.tfplan  
terraform apply main.tfplan
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]